# Request mapping and static fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, compiler-errors, static, request-mapping

I am trying to set value for `@RequestMapping` annotation as follows:
@RequestMapping(value = VALUE)

```
@RequestMapping(value = VALUE)
public class SomeClass {
  public final static String value = randomValue();
  public static randomValue() {
     return "some random stuff here";
  }
}
```

Now, I've noticed that is not legit since I got this error:

> Attribute value must be constant

Can someone explain me why this is happening, please?

Comment: you can't have random value as an endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Attribute value must be constant

Simply means that you can not assign a variable or some random values like `VALUE` for an endpoint. You should supply a constant string or multiple of it like the examples below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/value")
public class SomeClass {}

@RequestMapping("/value")
public class SomeClass {}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/value", "/"})
public class SomeClass {}
```

Comment: You can use `public final static String value = "some random value"` and works. Why doesn't it work with `public final static String value = randomValue();` ?

Comment: you should remove the `final` keyword then it would work. when you declare a variable as final, it should have a constant value

Comment: It's not going to work by removing `final` since `@RequestMapping` requires constants.

Comment: @DonatoAmasa, so, are you saying that `public final static String VALUE = randomValue();` isn't a constant?

Comment: I'm referring to the variable `value` declared on the class `SomeClass`